# Oracle SQL query to get the difference value with two where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause, difference

Im trying to make a query  to get the difference  of avg(score1+score2/2) from 'current' and the most recent 'archived' . to do a chart on Oracle Apex

Table name: myTable

```
id | score1 | score2 | status | date
------------------------------------------
1  |   10   |   20   |  current|  07/09/19
2  |   20   |   30   |archived| 04/09/19
3  |   15   |   35   |archived| 02/09/19
```

wanted the result: 
(avg(score1 + score2/2) where  status = 'current') - (avg(score1 + score2/2) where  status = 'archived' only the most recent)

Im tried

Comment: Sample data *and* desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . one method is conditional aggregation:

```
select max(case when status = 'current' then score_avg end), as current_score,
       max(case when status = 'archive' then score_avg end), as last_archive_score,
       (max(case when status = 'current' then score_avg end) -
        max(case when status = 'archive' then score_avg end)
       ) as diff
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by status order by date desc) as seqnum,
             (score1 + score2) / 2 as score_avg
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

I am guessing that you really want `(score1 + score2) / 2)`.  However, if you want `score1 + score2 / 2`, then use that expression instead.

Comment: @paoloricardos . . . What is missing?  There is nothing obviously wrong with the code.

Answer (score 0):

u want this?

```
select status , avg(score1 + score2/2) from you_table
group by status
```

or

```
select (select  avg(score1 + score2/2) from you_table
where  status='current')-(select  avg(score1 + score2/2) from you_table
where  status='archived') diff from dual
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using

`min/max(score1) keep (dense_rank first order by "date" desc) over (partition by status)`

to compute the **archived** case, and an ordinary arithmetic average computation for current case (depending on the sample data, there exists only one row for **current** case )

```
with myTable( id, score1, score2, status, "date" )as
(
 select 1, 10, 20, 'current' , date'2019-09-07' from dual union all
 select 2, 20, 30, 'archived', date'2019-09-04' from dual union all
 select 3, 15, 35, 'archived', date'2019-09-02' from dual 
), t as
(
 select
   case when status = 'current' then ( score1 + score2 ) / 2 end as curr,
   case when status = 'archived' then
   (
    (
     min(score1) keep (dense_rank first order by "date" desc) over (partition by status)+
     min(score2) keep (dense_rank first order by "date" desc) over (partition by status)
    )/2
   )
   end as arch
   from myTable
)
select max(curr)-max(arch) as "Avg.Result"
  from t;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=b7c283f4c01073610a4caedc8f67278a)</kbd>